# Bootstrap 4.1 navbar active class color doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
$('.navbar-nav .nav-item').click(function(){
    $('.navbar-nav .nav-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 nav-justified">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('home'); ?>">Home
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('home/page1'); ?>">Page One</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('home/page2'); ?>">Page Two</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('home/page3'); ?>">Page Three</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('home/page4'); ?>">Page Four</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried to change my navbar active class color onclick. But it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Use (see fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/so8e5pug/7/):**

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link{
    color:red!important;
}
```

```js
$('.navbar-nav .nav-item').click(function(){
    $('.navbar-nav .nav-item.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.navbar-light .navbar-nav .active>.nav-link{
    color:red!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 nav-justified">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('home'); ?>">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('home/page1'); ?>">Page One</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('home/page2'); ?>">Page Two</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('home/page3'); ?>">Page Three</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('home/page4'); ?>">Page Four</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the working demo :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.navbar-nav .nav-item').click(function(){
    $('.navbar-nav .nav-item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
})
});
```

```css
.navbar-nav>li.nav-item.active>a.nav-link{
  text-decoration:none;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav w-100 nav-justified">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page One</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page Two</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page Three</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Page Four</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```